# Accessing a website deployed in a virtual machine from local server outside the network

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, deployment, iis-8, windows-server

I have a virtual machine (WINDOWS SERVER 2012) running in our local server and I deployed my website on it using INTERNET INFORMATION SERVICES or IIS. I want to access it outside the network. What should I do?

I tried to get the public ip address. But i dont know where to find it.

Comment: Escalate this to your network administrators please. This is not a programming question, so off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

In virtual machine setting, you can find MAC address.
[image]

Then run `arp -a`. Find the MAC address and the IP will be on the side.

```
C:\>arp -a
Interface: 192.168.x.x --- 0x1c
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.xxx.xxx        00-0c-29-56-bd-36     dynamic
```